# How to get notification from UWP app service in the main app?

Tags: c#, uwp, event-handling, background-task, uwp-app-service

I implement UWP app service (windows runtime component) as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service). It is working fine and as far as I understand it is out-of-process background task by its nature.

What I need: to get notification in the main app when

```
private void OnRequestReceived(AppServiceConnection sender, AppServiceRequestReceivedEventArgs args)
{

}
```

is finished (when my background task is completed). I tried static event/event handler but when I set event handler from the main app, it is null during background task execution.

Another thing I tried is to subscribe to Completed event of background app from the main app. But `BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks` is empty in the main app, should I additionally register uwp app service as background task? Now it is specified in the manifest with name/entry point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your out-of-process model App Service into an in-process model, and handle task complete event in **App.xaml.cs** .

You can refer to this document [Convert an app service to run in the same process as its host app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/convert-app-service-in-process).

> Remove the EntryPoint attribute from the  element because
> now OnBackgroundActivated() is the entry point that will be used when
> the app service is invoked.
>
> Move the service logic from its separate background task project into
> methods that can be called from OnBackgroundActivated().

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and let you know. It seems it really makes things simple and allow to get rid from windows runtime component